# What is the transaction life cycle?

Tags: transactions, metamask, nodes, sendtransaction

When I want to send 1ETH from an address A to address B, utilizing for example Metamask, what's going on behind the scenes?

1. At the time that I click on submit/send the 1 ETH, does Metamask try to validate my transaction? Or a node tries to validate my transaction?
2. Is Metamask connected to a lightweight node?? I guess this happens automatically and I don't need to do any configurations?
3. If my transaction is validated (either from Metamask or a node - related to question 1), then the transaction should be validated by all nodes? Or we just need a validation from one node?
4. What does a node specifically when validating a transaction?? For example, just checking the digital signature??
5. If the transaction is valid, then it is propagated to all nodes or only to miners????
6. When the block is mined, then the block is propagated to all nodes or to other miners???

Thank you in advance.
It would be great and I would be thankful if you could give your insight into the previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think that MetaMask has some of the checks implemented, so that you don't send transactions that will fail. The node MetaMask connects to only forwards the transaction to the miner, so it does no validation.
2. MetaMask uses [Infura](https://infura.io/) in order to connect to the network, to send transactions and query it. You can use it with any of the networks included by default, but if you want to add an unsupported network, you need to pass your own RPC endpoint URL to MetaMask.
3. The transaction needs to be validated by a miner and included into a block. Any node can validate it, but only the validation that miner does really matters.
4. When the transaction is validated it compares the old state of the chaindata to the state that would be caused by the transaction. So check for underflows and overflows and so on.
5. Transaction gets propagated to the chain (all of the nodes) but is only stored in the tx pools of miners until it's validated.
6. When the block that contains the transaction is mined, it is propagated to all of the nodes, mining and others as well.